# How to migrate/transfer Office365 host server?

Tags: email, office365, hosting

I am changing my IT provider for my business. My current provider told me that they are hosting our Office365 and bundled apps (on an Exchange server) and that if I just switch hosts we will lose our email and data.

- I'm wondering what can be done to assist with this migration?
- Is there a step by step guide or something that I could follow?

Because I am sure it is not as easy as swapping hosts. I have my own domain and domain controller in house. Just our email service is hosted. Any help or guidance is incredibly helpful.

Comment: Did you contact Microsoft email Support?  I recall (from prior customer work) that they provide a (paid) service for this.

Comment: Your new provider needs to offer a migration process. You need to ask them. You can't do it without control over old & new provider spaces as part of the transition. I just transitioned my own domains structure; this was an offer from the new provider [with caveats, 'scripts should work but might not depending on your last provider...']. Fortunately I didn't need the service as my prime aim was get get away from Outlook/365/Exchange forever. POP3 FTW :P

Comment: @Tetsujin I am thinking of being my own IT provider. my business is not large. A file server with less than a TB of data and 10 email addresses and those 10 accounts have bundled apps (word, excel, etc). My current provider is giving me access to his system to complete the migration so in theory I have access to both old and new spaces.

Comment: @John I had not thought about asking Microsoft. I will look into that option though